# What fraction of energy goes in sound / heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, acoustics

Let's take a really simple example - I drop a ball from a known height in uniform gravitational field. When the ball will collide with the ground , a fraction of the kinetic energy will be converted in heat , another in sound energy and another back in kinetic energy .

If I know every parameter of the surface ( density,Young Modulus,atomic structure ) and every parameter of the surrounding air ( pressure , temperature , atomic mass ) , how can I find what fraction of the kinetic energy will be converted in **sound energy** and what fraction in **heat**?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the answer isn't 'run an enormous numerical simulation of the thing'?

Comment: Maybe a simplified theoretical modeling of the presses will be good enough to find some answers .

Comment: if you ignore air resistance, then you can measure mgh when you drop it and when it rises to its peak again - then the energy difference is heat + sound

Comment: The question is : what fraction of that difference is sound and what fraction is heat ?

Comment: To model this, you also need to include the dissipative properties of both the floor and the ball (mostly the ball).  And you need to model the detailed deformation and contact region of the ball (to get any sliding friction that occurs when the ball compresses while the contact area expands).  Most of the mechanical energy dissipation occurs during the collision.

Comment: There is very little energy in sound: 60 dB is 1 microwatt per square meter.